# Pandoc (LaTeX → HTML) does not use specified .cls file

Tags: document-classes, conversion, pandoc, html

I'm attempting to use [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org) to convert some math-heavy LaTeX into HTML. To make the TeX code easier to read and write, I've factored some macros into a `.cls` file in the same directory, and used it as the document class for my TeX file. When I run Pandoc on the TeX file, it ignores the `.cls` file. **How can I indicate to Pandoc to use a specific `.cls` file when compiling a TeX file?**

### MWE:

Class file:

```
% eggs.cls
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{eggs}

\LoadClass{amsart}

\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}
\newcommand{\wo}{without}
```

TeX file:

```
% test.tex
\documentclass{eggs}
\title{Test}
\begin{document}
It is said that \wo{} $\Z$, there would be no ring theory.
\end{document}
```

The command `pdflatex test.tex` works correctly: `\wo` and `\Z` are expanded as in `eggs.cls`. But when I run `pandoc test.tex -s --mathjax -o test.html`, the class file is not parsed:

[image]

### Further details:

- I am using Pandoc 2.7.2, the most recent release, on Ubuntu 18.04.2.
- Pandoc has a few flags for specifying metadata. I tried the [`--metadata` flag](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--metadata) (full command `pandoc --metadata=documentclass:eggs.cls test.tex -s --mathjax -o test.html`), but nothing changed.
- I also tried the [`--variable` flag](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--variable), and it also didn't help (as expected, since this flag is for the writing phase of Pandoc).

Googling this problem turned up [an old Github issue](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1615) with the same question, but it was closed as probably solvable, and there wasn't much of an explanation given.

### Workable solutions:

- If there's some setting (config file, environment variable) I can specify that leads Pandoc to parse the `.cls` file correctly, that would be best.
- Alternatively, is there some way to preprocess the `.tex` and `.cls` files into a `.tex` file based on a standard document class? (I'd be fine assuming the `.cls` file is based on a standard one.) Then I could feed the preprocessed file to Pandoc.

### Non-workable solutions:

- I'm not interested in a solution using `tex4ht` or variants in place of Pandoc: for some reason it does not work well with my project.
- In this MWE I could of course manually move the new commands into the preamble of the `.tex` file. However, I have a lot of `.tex` files I'd like to process, to the point where doing this manually would be too time-consuming.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need this to be a class and not a package?  Or even a simple `\input`?

Comment: @AlanMunn yes. In the original context of this problem (not just the MWE), the `.cls` file is more like an actual class file, and it would be a pain to convert it into a package and then update a few dozen TeX files by hand. If that is the only way forward, though, then I would be OK with it.

Comment: I suspected that might be the case. But changing it to a package does seem to do the trick, at least for your simple example.

Comment: why doesn't `tex4ht` work for your project? it can compile your MWE without problems.

Comment: Currently pandoc simply ignores documentclass, but it would be a nice improvement if it tried to read parse a local documentclass as it does with usepackage.  Why don't you put up an issue for this on pandoc's tracker, https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues, and we'll see what can be done?

Comment: @michal.h21 that's good to know! I initially tried `tex4ht` but I quickly got some pretty bizarre errors (e.g. a complete absence of `<p>` tags) that a Google search suggested didn't happen to anyone else, which is why I tried Pandoc. But if Pandoc doesn't pay attention to the document class at all, then I'll certainly give `tex4ht` another try!

Comment: @JohnMacFarlane would it not just be closed as a duplicate of [this closed issue from 2014](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1615)?

Comment: @ArunDebray - well, a lot has changed since 2014; back then we didn't even parse .sty files.